# Issues installing Apache2 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, 18.04, apache2

i'm a new Linux user and i'm trying to install Apache2, but when i enter this command

```
systemctl status apache2.service
```

i am getting this error

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-10-01 15:48:12 -03; 31s ago

out 01 15:48:12 lorena apachectl[23938]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set
out 01 15:48:12 lorena apachectl[23938]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
out 01 15:48:12 lorena apachectl[23938]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
out 01 15:48:12 lorena apachectl[23938]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
out 01 15:48:12 lorena apachectl[23938]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
out 01 15:48:12 lorena apachectl[23938]: Action 'start' failed.
out 01 15:48:12 lorena apachectl[23938]: The Apache error log may have more information.
out 01 15:48:12 lorena systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
out 01 15:48:12 lorena systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
out 01 15:48:12 lorena systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

How do i fix it? I'm just installing for use rancid.

Comment: Some other app is using port 80 on your system and that is apache's default port, give apache another port

Comment: Thank you, but how i do that? i'm sorry, i started using ubuntu two months ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the ports for apache in two places:

1. `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, and
2. `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

There you will need to modify for (1) the line:

```
Listen 80
```

to say

```
Listen 8080
```

And for (2), the line

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
```

Then restart apache with `sudo systemctl restart apache2`, Note I use `8080` here you can use any other port.

Also note:

> Port numbers 0 to 1024 are reserved for privileged services and designated as well-known ports. This list of port numbers  are specified in RFC 1700.
>
> Port numbers range from 0 to 65535, but only port numbers 0 to 1023 are reserved for privileged services and designated as well-known ports. The following list of well-known port numbers specifies the port used by the server process as its contact port.

```
1      TCP Port Service Multiplexer (TCPMUX)
5      Remote Job Entry (RJE)
7      ECHO
18     Message Send Protocol (MSP)
20     FTP -- Data
21     FTP -- Control
22     SSH Remote Login Protocol
23     Telnet
25     Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP)
29     MSG ICP
37     Time
42     Host Name Server (Nameserv)
43     WhoIs
49     Login Host Protocol (Login)
53     Domain Name System (DNS)
69     Trivial File Transfer Protocol (TFTP)
70     Gopher Services
79     Finger
80     HTTP
103    X.400 Standard
108    SNA Gateway Access Server
109    POP2
110    POP3
115    Simple File Transfer Protocol (SFTP)
118    SQL Services
119    Newsgroup (NNTP)
137    NetBIOS Name Service
139    NetBIOS Datagram Service
143    Interim Mail Access Protocol (IMAP)
150    NetBIOS Session Service
156    SQL Server
161    SNMP
179    Border Gateway Protocol (BGP)
190    Gateway Access Control Protocol (GACP)
194    Internet Relay Chat (IRC)
197    Directory Location Service (DLS)
389    Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP)
396    Novell Netware over IP
443    HTTPS
444    Simple Network Paging Protocol (SNPP)
445    Microsoft-DS
458    Apple QuickTime
546    DHCP Client
547    DHCP Server
563    SNEWS
569    MSN
1080   Socks
```

> Well-known ports range from 0 through 1023.
> Registered ports are 1024 to 49151.
> Dynamic ports (also called private ports) are 49152 to 65535.

See [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1700.txt?number=1700) for more.

Source: https://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/portnumbers.asp